# How to Launch Guitar pro 6

Tags: installed-programs

I thought I would give this one more go,I recently downloaded the full linux demo version of guitar pro 6 (r11201). When I first tried to install with ubuntu software centre, I just got "Error" and it failed to install. I tried to install it (with a lot of help from you Guy's) using Terminal but could not get it to install. Someone on the Forum suggested I just double click the file to install, I had already tried to do this as mentioned above, but gave it a go. After several attempts it finally Installed.yah.So now I need to Know how to launch it. I have extracted the files so does anybody know the easiest, most successful way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a fix to your problem but more suggestion and my experience. [Tuxguitar](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tuxguitar/) might not be good option but I believe it's the best software come with more function that I used for my need to learn guitar. It's support .gp3 to gp5 file extension of Guitar Pro.

[image]

Just for your consideration. Hope it help with your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers I did have this and I note from your screenshot that you have a lot of different instruments on your score. could you tell me how you got these on your score, as when I looked at it before I could not see them?

Comment: Can the sound be output to internal sound card?

Comment: Welcome, the score I got it from the Internet and not mine, I'm still new at guitar and Ubuntu in general. Still learning at basic level of my free time. As for the sound, you could follow this workaround/instruction, [tuxguitar doesn't play any sound](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247204/tuxguitar-doesnt-play-any-sound). Make sure you choose Gervill.