# Sound issues- tuxguitar not working

Tags: soundcard, midi

Current setup: PPC G5, Ubuntu studio 12.04, Focusrite sapphire soundcard through USB.

Working fine through qjackCtl: Audacious midi, Audiocity (recording and playback), Ardour

No sound: Rosegarden, Tuxguitar, timidity

I suspect this is a Midi issue. My objective here is to get Tuxguitar to work, I just used Rosegarden to find a pattern.

My current output in tuxguitar: Realtime sequencer / Gervill; (already tried the others, they don't work either)

Regarding tuxguitar plugins, the only one I see related to Midi is "Fluidsynth settings"  where the soundfont points is FluidR3_GM.sf2, audio driver is alsa, 16bits, 64, 16. Java is 1.6.

The Java Souns API plugin is activated, and configured to "use default soundbank".

When I check Audacious, output plugin is Jack, and the Amidi-Plug preferences show 2 backends available, ALSA and Fluidsynth, with oundfonts= FluidR3_GS and _GM.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a few months since you have posted this, but have you gotten it to work yet? I saw in two other places that you have to have tuxguitar-alsa, tuxguitar-oss, and tuxguitar-jsa installed as well as timidity. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247204/tuxguitar-doesnt-play-any-sound) and [here](http://tuxguitar.herac.com.ar/tgwiki/doku.php?id=doc:no_sound) Hope that helps if you have not gotten it to work yet. Good luck! And happy jam'n!

Comment: pretty late in the day but Ubuntu 22.04.1   , new install of tuxguitar, only had to install the last two jsa and timidity, then in tuxguitar settings sounds I had the option of real time sequencer. works.