# TuxGuitar - no sound in 14.04

Tags: tuxguitar

I tried the solutions in [tuxguitar doesn't play any sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247204/tuxguitar-doesnt-play-any-sound) but they didn't help.

I don't see Timidity as an option of the midi port. I can play midi files through timidity.

How can I debug this further?

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 61):

I had the same problem, and I solved it this way:

```
sudo apt install tuxguitar-alsa tuxguitar-jsa tuxguitar-oss
```

after this, go to Tools->Settings->Sound and select `Gervill` as Midi Port.

Comment: Just like to note that this also fixed the issue on Ubuntu 15.04, using the JACK audio server with the pulseaudio-jack-module. Of course I don't think JACK had anything to do with the issue, I believe it was just not playing nice with PulseAudio until installing the tuxguitar-jsa package.

Comment: Installing via `apt` rather than `apt-get` has a surprisingly colorful progress bar.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem arose after update to 14.04LTS. Apparently tuxguitar-alsa was the problem. I removed that package and tuxguitar started working fine again.